# Accessing attachments from hosted feature service FDGB in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-online, feature-service, attachments

This might be an easy question, but I've created a hosted feature service on ArcGIS Online to collect data from the public. This data also includes attachments (primarily photos) which from my understanding can be downloaded for further analysis in ArcGIS desktop.

I've managed to export the feature service to a FGDB which contains a point file for the locations, a table with attachment info and a relationship class property file.

How do I actually view the attachments or get access to them in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ArcGIS Desktop, you can access them via the Identify window:
[image]

Comment: Wow, I guess it was an easy question. Completely missed that!

Comment: I struggled to work out how to access them my first time as well. Not sure why because it is right there and seems like it is obvious!

Answer (score 0):

If you have pictures in your attachments and simply want to view them, a slightly faster way would be to use the HTML Popup (identify) tool. It displays the image first and foremost.

[image]